# controll mouse cursor movement speed in unity

Tags: unity, input

Im searching for a way to lower my mouse movement cursor speed and not to let the user move it fast but i dont know how. i searched in internet but could not find something Usefull. thank you for helping.

Comment: Maybe when mouse movement occurs you could try and move the mouse in the opposite direction to the actual movement slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're getting mouse movement by Input.GetAxisRaw, you can simply multiply this by a sensitivity value, for example;

**Sensitivity Vector;**

```
Vector2 sensitivity = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

**Calculating factorized mouse movement**­

```
Vector2 mouseMovement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * sensitivity.x,
                                    Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * sensitivity.y);
```

To do this you'll need to setup your Input Manager (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input) with the following two values;

[image]

Alternatively, if you want the value to be fixed, (and not changed in an options menu for example), you can manually change the *Sensitivity* value of the two mouse fields to your liking. Hope this helped you.